# Still having a hard time with RoR MVC approach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I suppose it should do justice to state what I think I know so far as well as what I've done:

1) I created the app and did my first db migration; I now have my dev, test and production databases.  The dev db has a table called 'wines'.

2) I made a scaffold which created the necessary files.

3) The basic index/update/destroy methods are set up and I can browse the pages.

4) From what I gather, the ActiveRecord class "Wine" automatically inherits properties from the database?  Each column is a property and each row in the table 'wines' is a potentially instantiated object which is called from the wine_controller script.

The problem I'm having now is that I want to create a common layout that all controllers use.  The only things that will change will be the page title, potentially some <link> tags in the header, the <body> attributes (javascript onload events most likely) and whatever lies inside the <body> tag.

I find myself looking up functions that will do what I want (like "favicon_link_tag", "stylesheet_link_tag" and "auto_discovery_link_tag"...) but I can't find the right place to PUT them!  I know this has something to do with my lack of understanding of how things are executed/inherited.  For example if I were to declare @pageTitle in application_controller.rb and use @pageTitle in ApplicationHelper it won't work.  Or even using "stylesheet_link_tag" in application_controller.rb throws an error.  I'm just not getting something.

How does each thing relate to another in terms of chronological execution, scope, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your "app/views" directory there is a folder called "layouts." By default there should be an "application.html.erb" file in there, but if there isn't you can create it.

Your "application" layout file is the default layout file used by any view. However, if you want a particular controller to use a different view, you can override this. See this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/7-all-about-layouts), and [this one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for) is helpful too.

The main thing to understand is the content from any particular view will show up wherever the `yield` method appears in your application layout. The main 'yield' block gets the view file specified by your controller action, but you can mark anything inside any view to be passed to another yield block instead. For instance, the "title" example you gave could be passed to the head of your application layout. See this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title) for a detailed example of that.

For more, you should read the [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), and you might want to consider picking up a Rails starter book.

I got my feet wet with "[Beginning Rails 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430224339)," which was a phenomenal introduction to the framework. A couple days with that book and it was all making sense to me, and I was developing faster than I ever had before. Rails rocks once you get to know it, but it's definitely worth going through a book.

Please continue to ask questions, I'll help if I can :)

-EDIT- To answer your question about control flow, it basically works like this:

1. Your browser sends a GET request for a particular URL.
2. The router takes that request, matches it to a controller action, triggers that controller action, and provides the controller any parameters associated with the request. For instance: if you requested `example.com/posts/123?color=red` this would trigger the `SHOW` action of your `posts_controller`, and would pass {:color => 'red'} to the params hash. You would access that using `params[:color]`
3. The controller action does its thing, and when it's done it renders output. By default it renders whatever view is located in `app/<controller_name>/<action_name>`, and will whichever file matches the extension appropriate to the request (ie an AJAX request would trigger `<action_name>.js.erb` and a GET request would trigger `<action_name>.html.erb`.

   - You can override this using the `render` method, for example by passing `render 'foo/bar'` to render using the view for FooController, Bar action instead of your current action.
   - Note that no matter what you render, the data available to the view is whatever is in the specific controller action the router triggered, not the controller action that would 'normally' render that view.
4. The view file is parsed using the data from the controller that called it. If you have any `content_for` methods then the view code that is inside the `content_for` block will go where you tell it, otherwise everything else will go to the main YIELD block in your `application` layout (or whatever layout your controller specified instead).
5. The application layout is parsed, and the content from the view is inserted into the appropriate areas.
6. The page is served to the user.

That's a simplification in some ways, but I think it answers your question. Again, feel free to keep asking :)

Comment: I just finished absorbing some of the rest of your question... edit with more detail on the way...

Comment: I do understand as much about what you stated, so I'll try and be more concise in my problems.  The controller sends the yield to the view correct?  Then is the application_helper an intermediary between the controller and the view?  What is the helper's function?  What variables/methods does the view have in relation to the helper/controller?

Comment: Any helper file is just a place to stick big messy functions your view might need, so that you can keep them out of the way of your "design" code. Helper files are named after the view that they auto-load for, so you can have functions that are only used by one set of views, or you can use the ApplicationHelper to have a function available in all views. Control doesn't flow "through" the helper files.

Comment: Working off of the 'rails guide' you linked to, I put 'layout "main"' in the 'application_controller.rb' file and it's using the wines.html.erb file instead of main.html.erb.  If I were to put the 'layout "main"' inside the wines_controller.rb file, it works.  What gives?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never tried to override the layout for every controller. I think, though, that the biggest issue you need to understand is no matter what layout you call the view your controller renders is still going to be inserted into it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far, I've learned some good things.  Now back to one of my unanswered questions, I'm attempting to get the URL from the server environment variables from within the wines_controller.rb code and I'm getting an error message.    undefined local variable or method `request'    When using 'LIVE_SITE = !request.request_uri.include?("test")'.  I got that 'request.request_uri' bit off of the web and I'm not sure why it isn't working for me.

Comment: Umm, tell me why you need the URL and I bet I can tell you an easier way to get it...

Comment: For one I'd like to know whether the script is running on the production server or not.  Parts of my script will depend on that knowledge.  For example the e-blast will send out immediately if it's on the test site but it will save to a file for use by a cron job on the production site.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake - `Rails.env` will give you the current environment. You can also get boolean values for specific environments with the sugar methods like `Rails.env.production?`, which you can use for your conditional logic.

Comment: Jake, for what it's worth, I really think you should take the time to read a Rails book. It sounds like you're thinking about this like it's PHP. I know, because I came to Rails from PHP. People talk about "The Rails Way", and that sounds a little pompous, but what it really means is there's usually a very easy way to do most things, and no reason not to do it the easy way if you only knew that it existed. It sounds like you're not approaching things "The Rails Way" and you'd be much happier if you had some more background knowledge. You'll get that from a book much faster than from SO :)