# Why can I put params[:from] in the method parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey Guys,
I'm new to Ruby and Rails, I made a small test example:

/apps/helpers/

```
module HomeHelper
  def makeach(from, to, by)
    x = from
    while x <= to
      yield x
      x = x + by
    end
  end
end
```

/apps/view/home/new.erb

```
<form action="create" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="from" />
  <input type="text" name="to" />
  <input type="text" name="by" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Click it" />
</form>
```

/apps/views/home/create.erb

module HomeHelper

```
<% makeach(params[:from], params[:to], params[:by]) do |x| %>
<%= x %>
<% end %>
```

/apps/controllers/home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
    def create
    end
    def new
    end
end
```

After I post the form in `action new`, the `create view` outputs nothing in the browser
PS: I know there are a lot ways to improve my code, But here I just want to know why I got nothing.

Comment: Helpers do have access to params, did you try to convert it to integer? params[:from].to_i

Comment: Mm, just to be sure: generally, in a crud design, there is no create view. Either new or show is displayed according to the status of the save. Did you get that?

Comment: can you show your create method in the controller?

Comment: @rubyprince I just add the controller code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, one thing is you're missing is the basic idea of REST. For a solid explanation of how Rails handles control flow, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835032/still-having-a-hard-time-with-ror-mvc-approach/#4835043).

But, basically, when you set `resources :home` in your routes it defines [seven routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for your seven standard controller actions ( SHOW, INDEX, NEW / CREATE, EDIT / UPDATE, DESTROY ).

When you try to load a page in your browser you're sending a GET request. The NEW action accepts GET requests. The CREATE action only accepts POST requests (like submitting a form). So, after you POST your form to the CREATE action, you need to redirect to a page that accepts GET requests if you want to show the visitor something.

Alternatively it may be possible to override Rails default to allow CREATE to accept GET requests, but I would consider that to be a bad idea.

Probably the simplest thing you need to do is make sure your CREATE action in your controller looks like this:

```
def create
  (... do whatever processing of the params you want to do here ...)
  redirect_to home_path # OR whatever other path you want.
end
```

At the end of a controller action you can either render (default) or redirect. Redirect just jumps to another controller action and does whatever is in that action. Render typically shows a view with the same name as a controller action, but render has lots of options, [see here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

To access params in the view the best thing to do is to assign them to an instance variable. IE:

```
def ... # any action that accepts GET requests
  @value = params[:value]
end
```

However, params will not persist after a redirect. So if you POST to one action and redirect to another (the normal convention), you'll need to either save the params to the DB, or save them to [session](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm).

In your case it looks like you should store them in session since they don't seem to be attached to a model.

Then in the next controller action you would check if there are certain variables in session and put them in instance variables to use in your view.

IE:

```
@value = session[:value] if session[:value]
```

I know this is a lot to absorb, but I hope this helps you wrap your mind around what's going on. One final suggestion, buy and read [Beginning Rails 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430224339). It's short, sweet, too the point, only takes a weekend to work through, and by the end you'll really understand the big picture of how rails works and your productivity and future learning will be quadrupled.

Good luck!